# Function inside factory is not accessible from custom directive

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular App which has the following code in the script:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, FileAccessor) {
  $scope.countrynames = []
});

myApp.directive('country', function() {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {

    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/scape.html',
    controllerAs: 'dm',
    compile: function(scope, FileAccessor) {
      FileAccessor.fetchCountryDetails('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all').success(function(response) { //assigning the fetched countries to the scope object var
        scope.countrynames = response;
      });

    }
  }
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
})

myApp.factory("FileAccessor", ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    fetchCountryDetails: function(url) {
      return $http.get(url);
    }
  }
}]);
```

Inside scape.html, the following code is placed:

```
<div  ng-controller="Ctrl"   class="container" style="height:500px" >

    <select ng-model="model" ng-options="obj.name for obj in countrynames | orderBy: '-population'" placeholder="Select" autofocus>
        <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
    </select>
    {{model.name}}
    {{model.currencies[0]}}
</div>
```

As we can see, I am trying to access the function which is placed inside the factory, `FileAccessor` from the custom directive, `country`.

When I run it on browser, there is this error that pops on console:
angular.min.js:86 TypeError: FileAccessor.fetchCountryDetails is not a function

Can somebody please explain what went wrong along with the fixed code?

P.S. I want the HTTP requests to be processed only through the factory(as a requirement).

Edit 1: Including the Plunkr link here: http://plnkr.co/edit/gXQKBd?p=info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analysing your code and agreeing with @CozyAzure, I could see that there is this controller `Ctrl` which doesn't do anything in the script.

Do you really need this? Eliminate it from your script.js and index.html and do a run. This would surely fetch the data in the desired way.

Answer (score 1):

Inject the service at your directive declaration, **NOT** in the compile function:

```
myApp.directive('country', function(FileAccessor) { //inject FileAccessor here
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'partials/scape.html',
    controllerAs: 'dm',
    compile: function(scope) {
      FileAccessor.fetchCountryDetails('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all').success(function(response) { //assigning the fetched countries to the scope object var
        scope.countrynames = response;
      });

    }
  }
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
})
```

Edit: There are quite a number of bugs inside your code, maybe you would want to read the docs?

One: Use `link` instead of `compile`, as `link` gives you the scope but `compile` doesn't:

```
myApp.directive('country', function(FileAccessor) {
  var directiveDefinitionObject = {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'scape.html',
    controllerAs: 'dm',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.test="Hello";
      FileAccessor.fetchCountryDetails('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all').then(function(response) { //assigning the fetched countries to the scope object var
        scope.countrynames = response.data;
      });
    }
  }
  return directiveDefinitionObject;
})
```

Two: Remove the `ng-controller` directive in your `scape.html` as this will override the of your directive:

```
<div class="container" style="height:500px"> //remove the ng-controller='Ctrl'
  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="obj.name for obj in countrynames | orderBy: '-population'" placeholder="Select" autofocus>
    <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
  </select>
  {{model.name}} {{model.currencies[0]}}
</div>
```

Here's a [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NFyswy?p=preview)

Comment: I tried that too. But this was not fetching the data. I will edit my question with a plunkr shortly. Please look into it.

Comment: @CozyAzure is right, checkout the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/5hdfz0a1/

Comment: @user5649133 see my edit, and i added a plnkr for you.